# Reading WAV audio file chunks issue in 1 file

Tags: audio

My software plays WAV files and I'm having a problem with one file a user sent me. Following the chunks in the file, it gets down to a umid chunk which is apparently 24 bytes in size but 24 bytes later is 4 null characters not another chunk name.

To me the file appears corrupt, yet 3 other players I've tried play it fine. I need to get to the data chunk which is way down at 1175544 bytes.

I've copied the top of the WAV file available for download.
http://www.stationplaylist.com/untitled.zip

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong or how other software is reading this file correctly.

Thanks,
Ross.

Answer (score 2):

In a RIFF chunk, the chunk size only includes the actual chunk data.  It does not include the chunk ID, the chunk size field, or data padding (chunk data is padded to an even multiple of 2 bytes, so make sure you are accounting for that - the chunk in question does not have padding, though).

In the file you uploaded, the `umid` chunk has a data size of 24, and there are not 4 nulls following the data.  24 bytes after the chunk data, the next 4 bytes are `44 47 44 41` (`DGDA`).  Here is a screenshot from a hex editor, the highlighted portion is the entire `umid` chunk:

[image: full chunk]
Full Chunk

Here is the chunk breakdown:

[image: chunk ID]
Chunk ID

[image: chunk size]
Chunk Size

[image: chunk data]
Chunk Data